# Click a Dropdown Menu Button using Watin

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, watin

I am testing a website using `Watin` in the page there is dropdown menu button like [image: <code>\[Download|V\]</code>] if I find that button and click it clicks the entire button and selects the first Option in the menu but I want to click the `V` of the button to show the `dropdown` menu(`div`) and select the option from it the code I had tried to click the button

```
ff.Button(Find.By("aria-describedby", "x-auto-456")).FireEvent("onmouseover");
ff.Button(Find.By("aria-describedby", "x-auto-456")).FireEvent(" Onmousedown");
ff.Button(Find.By("aria-describedby", "x-auto-456")).Click();
```

the Button `HTML`

```
<button class="x-btn-text" style="position: relative; width: 16px;" type="button" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="x-auto-456">
```

**Edit:**

I had tried to find the co-ordinates of the Image in the button and then click it with the below code but its slightly not working kindly any one point me how to click the button and show the `div` Instead of selecting a option automatically,

```
NameValueCollection eventProps = new NameValueCollection();
eventProps.Add("clientY", "240");
eventProps.Add("clientX", "240");
ff.Button(Find.By("aria-describedby", "x-auto-456")).FireEvent("onClick",eventProps);
```

Comment: The select element is dynamically generated, or it is already there, if it is already present, just go for the select element.

Comment: @VinayPratapSingh Its dynamically generated after a `Checkbox` is checked the checking of checkbox is done perfectly using `WATIN`

Comment: Can you show us the HTML markup structure for the dropdown? Knowing that will be the key to solving this problem.

Comment: @GregBurghardt The Dropdown(div) HTML will only be visible after the Button click I am stuck on the button click itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding the button correctly:

```
Button button = ff.Button(Find.ByClass("x-auto-457"));
```

You need to find the button by its class name. Be aware that will find the first `<button>` or `<input type="button|submit|reset">` element with that class name. If you still aren't getting the correct button, check to see how many buttons on the page have `x-auto-457` for a class attribute value.

Comment: I am finding the button and clicking it correctly but my problem is It is clicking the button and instead of showing the div it is selecting a option in the div and starts processing.

Comment: As one of my friend suggested Can I get the co-ordinates of the Image in the button and click it